# Firebase database returns null at beginning of each new node

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database

I have been having a bit of difficulty creating and displaying separate node from my Firebase database.

Here is a shot of a child node called `"Units"`, as it looks in the Firebase console, under which I wish to have separate single `"Unit"` nodes(1,2,3...) each with their own properties.

[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong but when the data returns there is a `null` at the beginning of each new child node that causes the data to display incorrectly when iterated over in the view.

Here is a snapshot of the `console.log` in the browser as the data comes back:

[image]

As you can see there is a `null` at the top of each new nested node before the actual data. I am thinking maybe it is something to do with the (1,2,3) nodes not having any values, but if I give them values I can no longer nest data inside each unit.

I am relatively new to Firebase so forgive me if I am making some basic error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

When you use numeric property names, Firebase will see if you're trying to store an array. The [legacy documentation on firebase.com](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase) had this to say about it:

> when data is read using `val()` or via the REST api, if the data looks like an array, the server will render it as an array. In particular, **if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values, then it is treated as an array.**

Since your data satisfies these criteria, Firebase returns it as an array. And since array are 0-based, it adds the missing 0th element.

To prevent this, you have a few options:

- Don't use numeric keys, but use Firebase `push()` to generate your keys
- Don't use numeric keys, by prefixing your numbers with a constant string: `Unit1`, `Unit2`, etc
- Start counting from 0 (good suggestion from André Kool)

OK, those are really the only options I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I changed the individual `unit` nodes to unit1,unit2 etc. and it worked! However, I was wondering, why Firebase also added `null` to the top of the nodes without numeric values, ie. `occupants` and `ownerNames`.

Comment: @Frank Or start from 0 instead of 1.

Comment: @mikeym the behavior is the same on every level: if it seems like an array, the Firebase client will turn it into an array (and thus pad with a `0` in your case).

Comment: Adding 0 at starting doesn't help, this problem gets deeper when a child get deleted and Firebase will fill the empty place with NULL. I will only recommend this method if you are 100% sure there won't be any removal in future.