# How to retrieve child value from child in firebase with javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase Structure]

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("games/" + gameId + "/patterns");
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot){
  var pattern = snapshot.key;
  console.log(pattern);
});
```

This is giving only the key.
What if I want to extract the player name whose status = 0

I know the snapshot contains every child data I need to extract because when i use

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("games/" + gameId + "/patterns");
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot){
  var value = snapshot.val();

  console.log(value);
});
```

I am getting the data like this..

[image: Snapshot Value]

I am not able to get the child's data as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you extract is a regular JavaScript/JSON object, so you can access its members as you would do with any other JavaScript object. Your `1`, `2`, `3` level keys will be converted to an array by Firebase, which means it adds a `null` item at the start of that array. For more about that, see: [Firebase database returns null at beginning of each new node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156533/firebase-database-returns-null-at-beginning-of-each-new-node/39156575#39156575)

To loop over all child nodes under the child of `patterns` that was changed and get the players whose `status` is `0` you'd do something like:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("games/" + gameId + "/patterns");
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    if (child.val() && child.val().status == "0") {
      console.log(child.val().player);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks Frank.. the post you mentioned cleared all the confusion I was having!